# How to count visitor of one website from another website(which are on totally different domain)

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net

I want to count the visitor of a website(which is located totally different domain) from my website.Just like [Alexa is counting the visitor of all website](http://www.alexa.com/) . How it can be done? Any idea or implementation please. Thanks in advance.

For all i clarify my question.

*Suppose I want to count the visitor of www.yahoo.com. The total number of visitor, per day or per month etc. I know this will be very easy if i am the owner of www.yahoo.com, but if i have no connection with www.yahoo.com, then is it possible to know their visitor or any statistics?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alexa uses statistics from it's toolbar to estimate the number of visits on a website. I would suggest using an API such as the [Alexa API](http://aws.amazon.com/awis/) in order to find out this information as opposed to gathering it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can count them on the client side using document.referrer and then if the prior domain matches your objective increment a number stored in localStorage and beacon this number back to the mothership with AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

***if you want to make stat to your own visitors  I use Some thing like This***

**Using javascript code**  like google

*when you register in google analytic you will have javascript code to add in your website
this code will connect to google in any visit to site*

or using **1 pixel image** this image hosted on your website

this image insert data to your visitor database Using Code Of Site

Like

if i have client and i want to collect information about his visitors

i will add client to my clients in database

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id  + client_key   + client_name + client_email + client_website + STATUS      +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1   +  any key     +  Test       +  Test@domain +  http://www... + 1           +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

and  use his primary key as forign key in

visits table  which contain

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id + client_id + time + ip + referrer  + systeminfo +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

and get image like

```
<img src='http://mywebsite.com/stat.php?cid=client+key' alt='' />
```